# socket.io works in Chrome-Ripple but not on device (VS15 & Cordova)

Tags: visual-studio, cordova, socket.io

Using  `Visual Studio 15`, `Cordova` and this command to connect the server:

```
var socket = io.connect('http://my.server:8000/', { 'forceNew': true });
```

debugging with `RIPPLE` is working just fine, but when running on `Device` (deploy & debug with usb) the connection is not working.

`socket.connected` returns `false`.

`config.xml` content:

```
  <access origin="*" />
  <allow-navigation href="*" />
  <allow-intent href="itms:*" />
  <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />
```

I have no idea what could it be, thanks.

EDIT:

Server and Client are using the same socket.io version.

`debug mode` outputs `TransportError` error.

Answer (score 0):

Eventually this was solved by set websocket connection:

```
io.connect('http://server:8000/', { forceNew: true, transports: ['websocket'] })
```

I'll update when I'll find the reason for this.